# How can I cast string to Uri in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Width="1024" Height="1280">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Image MaxWidth="500" MaxHeight="500" Source="{DynamicResource H_ThankYou_Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>  
    </Grid>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="H_ThankYou_Image" UriSource="{DynamicResource H_ThankYou_ImagePath}"/>
    <sys:String x:Key="H_ThankYou_ImagePath">"../../../../Graphics/Icon_Email.png"</sys:String>
  </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

It says an object of type System.String cannot be applied to a property that expects the type System.Uri.

when I try something like this:

```
<sys:Uri x:Key="H_ThankYou_ImagePath">"../../../../Graphics/Icon_Email.png"</sys:Uri>
```

it says the name "uri" does not exist in the System namespace??

Edit1:

I tried using the solution @Clemens suggested:
It works for the first run(Icon_Email.png), however when I'm trying to dynamically change the value like this: 
`userControl.Resources["H_ThankYou_ImagePath"] = "../../../../Graphics/Icon_Email2.png"`
the follow error occurs:

```
Cannot convert '<null>' from type '<null>' to type
'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' for 'en-US' culture with default 
conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. 
NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: ImageSourceConverter cannot convert from (null).
```

Comment: It should work if you directly use `H_ThankYou_ImagePath` as value for the `Image.Source` property. WPF has built-in conversion from `string` to `ImageSource`.

Comment: It doesn't when it's a dynamicResource. Source="../../../../Graphics/Icon_Email.png" works, however.

Comment: And you can't use StaticResource?

Comment: not in my case. I need a way to dynamically change the picture in run time.

Comment: just tried using system.dll. Unfortunately, Uri does not has any accessible constructor :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ugly hack works for me:

```
<Image DataContext="{DynamicResource H_ThankYou_ImagePath}" Source="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: @McKevin Just checked it and successfully replaced the H_ThankYou_ImagePath resource with another image path string.

Comment: the ugly working! but is there any beauty hack available?

Answer (score 2):

Building from AnjumSKhan's answer :

Define your namespace :

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
```

Define your URI :

```
<sys:Uri>pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyNameHere;component/Path/To/Image.jpg</sys:Uri>
```

So the problem was that you were referencing the wrong assembly. Just change your namespace from `mscorlib` to `System` and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

Assuming Penguins.jpg file is present in root folder.

Namespace mapping

```
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:sys1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
```

Resource declaration

```
    <sys1:UriBuilder x:Key="UKey">
        <sys1:UriBuilder.Host>
            <x:Static Member="sys:String.Empty" />
        </sys1:UriBuilder.Host>
        <sys1:UriBuilder.Scheme>
            <x:Static Member="sys:String.Empty" />
        </sys1:UriBuilder.Scheme>
        <sys1:UriBuilder.Path>
            pack://application:,,,/Penguins.jpg
        </sys1:UriBuilder.Path>
    </sys1:UriBuilder>
```

Usage:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Uri, Source={StaticResource UKey}}"/>
```